# Results show up in Enterprise Search results but not This Site results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-search

This is happening in our SharePoint Online environment.  We have a sub-site that is not returning results for "Search This Site" (osssearchresults.aspx) but when you click on Everything (Enterprise search), results from the site are shown.  This shows that the content is crawled since results are returned in Enterprise search.  It seems like just the "This Site" scope or site specific search is broken.

Other sub-sites in the Site Collection are returning "This Site" results appropriately so it is not a SC level issue.  All settings match the working sub-sites as well.

While setting this sub-site search to use the Enterprise Search Center is working, the preferred method is sub-site search returns "This Site" results first and then the user can go to Everything if they wish.

Any thoughts on where else to look would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this particular scenario was to change the default Result Sources to one of the other sources (I changed it from Local SharePoint Results to Documents).  I gave it 30 minutes to propagate the changes and then reverted the default result source back to Local SharePoint Results.  This seemed to "reset" the search results and search is now functioning as expected when searching the "This Site" scope.

Comment: Thank you for you sharing, you could mark your reply as answer and It will do great help to those who meet the similar question in this forum.

Comment: Thank you Julie!  I have marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when SharePoint Online is configured to obtain search results from a source other than Local SharePoint Results.

Please check the Result Sources configuration for the subsite:

1. Browse to the affected SharePoint Online subsite.
2. Click the gear icon for the **Settings** menu, and then click **Site
   settings**.
3. Under **Search**, click **Result Sources**, and confirm that **Local
   SharePoint Results** has the check mark for **Default** assigned to it.
4. If the check mark isn't next to **Local SharePoint Results**, click the
   drop-down arrow for **Local SharePoint Results**, and then click **Set as
   Default.**

   [image]

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/search/search-results-not-return#if-this-issue-occurs-for-a-subsite-check-the-result-sources-configuration-for-the-subsite

------------------Update-------------------

Please click "Use the same Search Navigation links as my parent" then compare the result.

[image]

Comment: Hi Julie,
Thanks for the reference.  This subsite is configured with Local SharePoint Results as the default.  It is the only subsite in this Site Collection that is having this issue.

Comment: I have updated my reply, please check it.

Comment: Hi Julie, that option was also already checked.  I've tried changing all of the settings to different ones and changing them back to see if they would "reset" but to no avail.  I've also went through the site and looked at the search visibility settings and everything is set to show up in the search results.